# NTP not syncing immediately on windows

Tags: ntp

I am trying to sync with NTP server, but server is responding with below messages. Below are the wireshark captures.

```
Flags: 0x0c
11.. .... = Leap Indicator: unknown (clock unsynchronized) (3)
..00 1... = Version number: NTP Version 1 (1)
.... .100 = Mode: server (4)
Peer Clock Stratum: unspecified or invalid (0)
Peer Polling Interval: invalid (0)
Peer Clock Precision: 0.000008 sec
Root Delay:    0.0000 sec
Reference Timestamp: Jan  1, 1970 00:00:00.000000000 UTC
```

My ntp.conf file has below enteries:

```
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 0
restrict 127.127.1.0
```

After some 3 minutes the sync is happening properly.But its not happening immediately. Can anybody help me in resolving.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's normal for the Windows Time Service.  It syncs at startup, and then only periodically thereafter.  If you want to see an immediate sync, you can try restarting that service.

I've also had situations where the time adjustment required was too much, and it refused to sync with the time server for that reason.  You should be able to see events in Event Viewer in cases where the Windows Time Service cannot sync its time for some reason.

Comment: Actually I have stopped service for windows time and started the ntp as in my project we are using vxworks as ntp client which will get its time from NTPserver(windows). Here the issue is it wont sync up immediately, but after 3 minutes it will start syncing periodically(the delay we have used is 45 seconds. i.e. for every 45 seconds client will send NTP request)

Comment: Ok, never mind then.  I thought your client was Windows.  I am not familiar with vxworks.